# How to create Storyboard with Height TargetProperty

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to animate the `Height` of a  `Border` `Height` by sizing it from `0` to `50`.

This is what I have tried:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="showAnimation">
     <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" 
                         From="0" To="50" 
                         DecelerationRatio=".9"
                         Duration="0:0:1" />
</Storyboard>
```

And got this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException:
>   ''System.Windows.Media.Animation.ThicknessAnimation' animation object
>   cannot be used to animate property 'Height' because it is of
>   incompatible type 'System.Double'.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the ThicknessAnimation with a DoubleAnimation because Height is a Double, not a Thickness

```
<Storyboard x:Key="showAnimation">
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" 
                     From="0" To="50" 
                     DecelerationRatio=".9" 
                     Duration="0:0:1" />
</Storyboard>
```